# How to show error pages in MVC if error occurred in different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC application uses error pages, configured in the web.config file. All errors display a single web page, regardless of the type of error. This works fine.

The problem I have though, is the exception isn't thrown in the web project, but in my BLL project. So, consider this

//My Web.Ui

```
public ActionResult Thing()
{
    Bll.Statics.DoThis();
    return View();
}
```

and my BLL is

```
public static void DoThis()
{
    throw new Exception("Kaboom");
}
```

The problem is, when the error occurs here, I don't see my 404 page, I get a standard 'browser' error page explaining something when wrong.

Do I simply just need to wrap all calls in Try Catch from my Controllers so I can throw (re-throw) the exception from the controller itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wrap all your calls in a `try-catch` block. On the other hand think about the exceptions that you might be catching. Do you want to catch `Exception` or you want to give different information, like in case of `SqlException` when you don't have connection to the database, etc. If all you want is to show your custom 404, then you might go with a generic option.

Comment: This is mostly more about logging - I have some handling else where for logging but I need to at least show the user a nice page saying "we know it's gone wrong". Thank you for the post. I do use proper catch statements (by exception type) when I try to fix it there and then :)